# Many to Many Relationship and the Create View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, many-to-many

I have an object `(Route)` that has 2 properties `(Donor and Agency)`.  Both Donor and Agency are both of type `Organization`.  In the database, I have a many to many `relationship` setup for `Route<>Donor` and `Route<>Agency`.  When I try to run my code, it tells me that I need to setup a ForeignKey for one of these relationships, but I'm kind of lost at this point.  Am I doing this right?  What am I missing?

Here is the Route Class...

```
public partial class Route
{
    public Route()
    {
        RouteOrg = new HashSet<RouteOrg>();
    }

    public int RouteId { get; set; }
    public int RouteOrgId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RouteOrg> RouteOrg { get; set; }
    public List<Organization> Donors { get; set; }
    public List<Organization> Agencies { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the Organization Class...

```
public partial class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        RouteOrgAgency = new HashSet<RouteOrg>();
        RouteOrgDonor = new HashSet<RouteOrg>();
    }

    public int OrgId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public int? RouteId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RouteOrg> RouteOrgAgency { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RouteOrg> RouteOrgDonor { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my OnModelCreating method...

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.6-servicing-10079");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.OrgId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.AddressId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.OrganizationTypeId);

            entity.Property(e => e.OrgId).HasColumnName("OrgId");

            entity.Property(e => e.AddressId).HasColumnName("AddressId");

            entity.Property(e => e.DateAdded).HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(100);

            entity.Property(e => e.Nickname).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.OrganizationTypeId).HasColumnName("OrganizationTypeId");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
                .HasColumnName("UserId")
                .HasMaxLength(450);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Route>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.DayOfWeekId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.FrequencyId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.TimeOfDayId);

            entity.Property(e => e.RouteId).HasColumnName("RouteId");

            entity.Property(e => e.DateAdded).HasDefaultValueSql("(getutcdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.DayOfWeekId).HasColumnName("DayOfWeekId");

            entity.Property(e => e.FrequencyId).HasColumnName("FrequencyId");

            entity.Property(e => e.RouteOrgId).HasColumnName("RouteOrgId");

            entity.Property(e => e.TimeOfDayId).HasColumnName("TimeOfDayId");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RouteOrg>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.RouteOrgId).HasColumnName("RouteOrgId");

            entity.Property(e => e.AgencyId).HasColumnName("AgencyId");

            entity.Property(e => e.DonorId).HasColumnName("DonorId");

            entity.Property(e => e.RouteId).HasColumnName("RouteId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Agency)
                .WithMany(p => p.RouteOrgAgency)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AgencyId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_RouteOrg_Agency");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Donor)
                .WithMany(p => p.RouteOrgDonor)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DonorId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_RouteOrg_Donor");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Route)
                .WithMany(p => p.RouteOrg)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.RouteId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_RouteOrg_Route");
        });
    }
```

I currently have the Create view showing everything correctly.  I'm showing the many to many relationship with a list of `check boxes` for Donors and one for Agencies.  I expect to be able to select as many of each of these types of `organizations` as I want, save it to the `DB`, and be able to `edit, view,` etc and keep all of the data.

UPDATE: I'm also getting this error when trying to run the project now...

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Both relationships between 'Organization' and 'Route.Agencies' and between 'Organization' and 'Route.Donors' could use {'RouteId'} as the foreign key. To resolve this configure the foreign key properties explicitly on at least one of the relationships.)'

Comment: Does an organization have a collection of type Route or RouteOrg ?

Comment: Yes, see the OP. I included the Organization class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `EF Core`, note that `EF Core` **won't** map a Many-To-Many relationship automatically for you.

Because one `Route` will have many `RouteOrgs` (instead of many `Donors` or `Agencies`), you shouldn't configure the two `Donors` and `Agencies` properties as fields of the table `Route`.

```
public partial class Route
{
    ...
    public List<Organization> Donors { get; set; }
    public List<Organization> Agencies { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you like, configure a `[NotMapped]` Attribute for these two fields:

```cs
public partial class Route
{
    ...

    public int? RouteOrgId { get; set; }    

    public virtual ICollection<RouteOrg> RouteOrg { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Organization> Donors { 
        get {
            return this.RouteOrg.Select(ro => ro.Donor);
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Organization> Agencies { get{
        return this.RouteOrg.Select( ro =>  ro.Agency);
    } }
}
```

When you want to get the Donors and Agencies of Routes, use `Include().ThenInclude()` to query as below:

```cs
var routes = await _context.Route
    .Include(r => r.RouteOrg)
        .ThenInclude(ro => ro.Agency)
    .Include(r => r.RouteOrg)
        .ThenInclude(ro => ro.Donor)
    ;
```

Comment: I basically had the Donor and Agency Lists so I could populate them with ALL of the organizations in the Controller so I could populate the CheckboxList.  Like so...

model.Donors = orgs.ToList().Where(o => o.OrganizationTypeId == 1).ToList();

Comment: @Fubak Don't mix up entity model with view models.

Comment: Can I return multiple models to my view?  I tried creating a MergeModel that had a bunch of objects on it that I could populate and return, but it ends up getting messy in the code

Comment: @Fubak No. You'll have only one view model for your view file. For your last edit: You'll fix that problem by **removing** the two `Donors` & `Agencies` properties of `Route` as I suggested above.